# Simplest way to do a web page login for a Node jsforce command-line app?

Tags: salesforcedx, node.js, jsforce

I have some automation that runs on Node/[jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) and am using this code:

```
    connect() {
        const command = `sfdx auth:web:login -r ${this._instanceUrl} --json`;
        const response = await this.execute(command);
        const parsed = JSON.parse(response);
        const connection = new jsforce.Connection({
            instanceUrl : this._instanceUrl,
            accessToken : parsed.result.accessToken
        });
        return connection;
    }

    execute(command) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            exec(command, (error, output) => {
                if (error) reject(error);
                resolve(output);
            });
        });
    }
```

to get the access token by running `sfdx auth:web:login` that opens the browser and returns the access token value.

Is there a simple way to do this avoiding the need for `sfdx` to be installed?

Comment: Do you want to avoid having to use a browser, too? That would affect the answer.

Comment: No @sfdcfox, here I specifically want to use the browser. I'm aware that there are a variety of non-browser alternatives.

Comment: jsforce [docs](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#oauth2) have an example of this,

Comment: Thanks @identigral, but as I read the part you linked to, the example is invoking an endpoint passing over the credentials rather than the opening of the login web page.

Comment: It redirects (`res.redirect...`), the authorization code  grant requires that. Their example is a bit short, it assumes you know express. [Here's a longer take](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce/issues/1144)

Comment: Hi @identigral, I'm looking for a way for only Salesforce to be getting HTTP requests so the machine running the CLI code does not have to have any internet visible address. Your link seems to require a local web server (express) to be started? Still not getting it. On my side, my customer is OK with installing `sfdx` so a simpler solution here is longer a concern for me. Thanks-you for your inputs on this.

Comment: @Keith If it has an IP on a local network and can route requests outside through proxy/etc, then redirects will work. Else, you have to acquire the token on another device and then transport it to this machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_overview.htm&type=5) in Salesforce, and then use [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow for Desktop or Mobile App Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5). I don't have time to prototype the entire thing at this the moment, but the general theory would be something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const open = require('open');
const app = express();
const port = 3333;
const loginUrl = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token';
const clientId = '...'; // from Connected App
const server = `https://localhost:${port}/`;

let tokenPromise;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // Output some html/js to grab the token in the url
});
app.get('/callback', (req, res) {
  // Read the token here
  tokenPromise.resolve(token);
});
app.listen(port, () => {
});

async connect() {
  open(`${loginUrl}&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${server}');
  let token = await new Promise((resolve)=>{tokenPromise={resolve}});
  // ... continue on
}
```

In theory, it should be relatively simple. You can even get a refresh token this way, so once logged in, you can stay connected indefinitely. Again, this is just a really simple example, but I think it should get you started.

Comment: Thanks! Think I'll keep this in my back pocket if having to install `sfdx` becomes a blocker (as it might) as it looks like something that will take a while to get right.

Comment: @KeithC Yeah, depending on experience, it could take a bit. I'll try and write up a gist or something this weekend that I can share.

Comment: That's great, though I should find out whether I need this this afternoon or not in a discussion with the customer.

Comment: Customer is happy to install `sfdx` so now not a problem I need to solve FYI.